# Scale internal NSViewControllers when Window Resizes

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

I am having trouble scaling my internal views when a window resizes.

My view hirachy looks like this:

`-> NSViewController
    -> NSView 
       -> NSImageView`

All that is inside a global NSWindowController (the default story board one).

I have tried adding constraints to do this, but I can't find the appropriate class to reference "self.window" so `NSLayoutConstraint` isn't working.

I am not sure how to override the default NSWindowController to then spawn my own windows because I am relying on the "Is initial View" tick box in storyboard.

What is the best way to go about this? I am honestly stuck and can't find any documentation about the best way to have your internal view controllers scale out with your main parent window.  Do I try to override NSWindowController and manage the top most viewcontroller from there?, or do I add constraints in the viewcontroller, or am I missing something obvious?